# image_transport republish with camera_info

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I using republish of image_transport as follows,

$ rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/usb_cam/image_raw out:=/usb_cam_repub/image_raw

In this case, there is no message in

/usb_cam_repub/camera_info

$ rostopic echo /usb_cam_repub/camera_info

does not show anything.

However,

$ rostopic echo /usb_cam/camera_info

shows camera parameters.

How can I copy /usb_cam/camera_info to /usb_cam_repub/camera_info ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35709/image_transport-republish-with-camera_info./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The republish node does not republish the CameraInfo message. You can use topic remapping to solve this problem. In the application which uses the republished image message, you should be able to remap the camera_info message back to the old one. Your call will look something like:

```
rosrun package binary usb_cam_repub/camera_info:=usb_cam/camera_info
```

You can read more about remapping arguments [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments)

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-06-06**:
Hi. Actually, this does not work. My problem is that when I subscribe /usb_cam_repub/image_raw in rviz, the rviz is finding /usb_cam_repub/camera_info by default, however, there is no topic. So I changed it to /usb_cam, then camera_info is loaded once, then I changed to /usb_cam_repub, it will work

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-06-07**:
Did you try running "rosrun rviz rviz /usb_cam_repub/camera_info:=/usb_cam/camera_info". I just did a quick test and it works for me.